# position:relative not working in IE9

Tags: html, css

I am developing a HTML page in which we have a table having `<thead>` tag used for the header section. Now I want to fixed this header section always on top. Following is the CSS code which I am using:

```
thead tr { 
   position:relative; 
   top: expression(offsetParent.scrollTop); 
}
```

However, this is only working in IE8. It is not working in IE9.
So how can we achieve the same in IE9?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: hmmm - I recall something about relative only works as child of absolute ?

Comment: @Mike: sorry I am not getting you.

Comment: @Mike - it is the opposite - absolute needs a relative parent or else it takes body as relative.

Comment: @easwee I think the most correct is to say that absolute positioning means "relative to the closest positioned (absolutely, relatively or fixed) parent". If there's no positioned parent, the element is positioned relatively to the root element.

Comment: @duri - yes but I saw no point in going into details with such a random comment.

Answer (score 2):

The [`expression` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an old IE-only feature that Microsoft has abandoned and doesn't support anymore in newer IE versions.

You should look into [`position: fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning) instead. (However IE6 doesn't support this, but there are workarounds available, that are easily googled if needed.)

Comment: well thanks for reply RoToRa..I had already tried position:fixed.But it keeping the header in fixed position but layout is not coming good.

Answer (score 1):

`expression` is only for oldie IEs, that's why it fails in IE9. To fix a `div` in a **cross-browser** way, use this snippets instead:

```
#div{
    position:fixed; 
/*The followings are for Oldie IE*/
    _position: absolute; 
    _top: expression(documentElement.scrollTop); 
}
```