# Getting postion:relative to work in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I have some trouble getting `position: relative` to work in IE9. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QWGta/10/) with the following code:

```
<div style="overflow:scroll;height:120px;">
<table id="table"  width="100%">
    <tr style="position:relative;background-color:#1b72a4;">
        <td>fff
        </td>
         <td>fff
        </td>
         <td>fff
        </td>
         <td>fff
        </td>
         <td>fff
        </td>
         <td>fff
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
         <td>data
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

I'm fixating the first row, by giving a style to first row like this: `style="position:relative;"`

However, mentioned style only works in IE7. I have to fixate first row in all versions of IE. What should I do?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120567/positionrelative-not-working-in-ie9

Comment: Dr.Dan but i dont have header tag and i dont want header tag tooo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want? You said you are **fixing** first row which I assume you want always on top, so `position: relative;` isn't the right thing to go for, use `position: absolute;` instead

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QWGta/11/)

CSS

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#table {
   width: 600px;
}

.fixed {
   position:absolute;
   background-color:#1b72a4;
}

.fixed td {
   width: 100px;
}

#table tr:nth-child(2) td {
   padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: if header tds are increase or data tds are increase then

Comment: you need to set width's yourself, else fix the width, use `table-layout: fixed;` than there's no question of the width to increase

Comment: @Alien see the link  have to make ROOM row fixed http://jsbin.com/uwuqut/2/edit when i apply ur code getting problems..

Comment: @lax I don't see any fixed header there, just take a look at `table-layout: fixed;` property, and apply there, I don't see and fixed width columns or tables there

Comment: @lax They are not fixed, just take a look at that property, and apply to your table

Comment: @lax leaving now, just a thing, instead of setting width using `width="70"` set style="width: 70px;" in each header td which should match it's corresponding column width

Comment: ur solution works in ie 7 proper but border not mix ups with data cells in ie 9

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20871/discussion-between-lax-and-mr-alien)

Comment: $('#tableAppointment td').css("width", "70px"); given height 70px to all td but still not works in ie 9